# Testing WPAD file locally with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, local, chrome, wpad.dat, wpad

I am in the process of making our WPAD script ipv6 ready.
I downloaded our current (working) WPAD script and configured the following options in

Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN settings

- Automatically detect settings unticked
- Use automatic configuration script ticked
- use proxy server for your LAN unticked

I tried the following Layouts for specifing the WPAD address:

- file://C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\wpad.dat
- file:///C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\wpad.dat
- file:////C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\wpad.dat
- file://C:/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/wpad.dat

While Chrome 33 works perfectly with each of theese lines IE doesnt work with a single one.
But if it loads the script from  it works perfectly fine.

Does anyone know how to get IE 11 to load a local wpad script ?

Comment: Have you seen [this discussion](http://serverfault.com/questions/54567/internet-explorer-isnt-auto-discovering-http-wpad-wpad-dat-auto-config) and [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/271361)? I'm thinking maybe it has to do with the way that IE caches the WPAD information, and that disabling the caching may allow you to conduct your tests.

Answer (score -2):

IE11 requires the wpad.dat file to be served out by a web server, eg. IIS.

From [Auto detect settings Internet Explorer 11](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn338137.aspx):

> Internet Explorer 11 creates a default URL template based on the host name, wpad. For example, `http://wpad.<domain>.com/wpad.dat`. Because of this, you need to set up a file or redirection point in your web server WPAD record, named wpad.dat. The wpad.dat record delivers the contents of your automatic configuration file.